# Complete Android management program for Windows

Tags: gratis, android, windows-7

I cannot find a complete, all-in-one program for Windows that allows me to:

- view, install, uninstall (and possibly update) apps
- backup contacts, app data and apps
- move apps from phone memory to SD card
- transfer pictures/files to and from the phone

So, is there a free program that does all the above? I need it to be wired because I might need to transfer a lot of pictures, and doing it wirelessly would takes ages.

Comment: Did you take a look at my site, and checked with [Manage your Android Device from your Computer](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement)? I'm not a Windows user, so I cannot give a good answer here from my own experience – but I'd bet [Droid Explorer](http://de.codeplex.com/) would match your needs. Its dev is active over at Android.SE if you get in trouble or need advice with it :) Alternative, maybe: [Moborobo](http://www.moborobo.com/index.html).

Comment: @Izzy I'll try Droid Explorer - screenshot looks good :)

Comment: So does support. Let me know if I shall make that an answer – I know where to collect some details for that :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Which is your Device and android version ?

Comment: @unique_id jelly bean

Answer (score 2):

Not very user friendly but you can do all of the above, and more, with the [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) (adb) command line tool.  Note that you need to enable debug connections first.

The tool is part of the Android Developer Studio which is **free** and cross platform so will work on:

- Microsoft® Windows® 8/7/Vista/2003 (32 or 64-bit)
- Mac® OS X® 10.8.5 or higher, up to 10.9 (Mavericks)
- Linux GNOME or KDE desktop

As a developer tool it can do just about anything, **including potentially breaking your device** so I would ***strongly recommend*** testing what you would like to do with one of the emulation packages **before** trying with your phone.

The good news is that as it is a command line tool you can write batch scripts to perform actions that you do regularly, e.g. backing up all contacts.

- You can copy any file, or directory hierarchy, from and to the device including pictures, contacts, etc.
- You can list installed software, uninstall it, install from .apk files, install to non-default locations - *this will break some apps*.
- and of course you can start to develop your own apps.

Some examples, *(all assuming that you have exactly one device connected via USB)*:

Tow install some app:

```
adb -d install C:\SomeDir\some_app.apk
```

Or to copy your music that is on your SD card to the local drive:

```
adb -i pull /storage/extSdCard/Music C:\Music
```

An introductory video is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sgzeh5_LzN4) or at tutorial is [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/adb-easy-tutorial/).

Comment: **The** correct answer. `adb` is your friend.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to copy files to and fro and install/uninstall/move apps? Or a link to a 'beginners guide' if possible? :)

Comment: Added a couple of brief examples and links.

Comment: Cool! I just need to try Izzy's suggestion now and compare the two :) +1 though

Comment: Droid Explorer is probably a gentler start but adb has the power and the ability to automate regular operations.

Comment: And you do not need the entire SDK for that, see: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) – Btw: Guess what *Droid Explorer* is using as backend? :)